# Algorithm for creating shapes out of elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I got a script that generates 100 elements and appends them to the site.
I'm using jquery to let the elements move to the left or right side but I was wondering if there would be some kind of algorithm to create a cross or a cirle out of those elements.

So you have 100 small boxes and the algorithm moves them around and formes a circle or other easy symbols.

I did some researching but I couldn't find something usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** This is a super hacky, quickly put together solution that has a couple obvious flaws, but I'm sure that you can work those out for yourself:

Here's what I might do (well, a little cleaner, but it would probably be along these lines):

```
$(function(){
    // generate the boxes
    for(var n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
        $("<div/>",
            {
                id: n,
                style: "width: 20px;\
                    height: 20px;\
                    background-color: red;\
                    position: absolute;",
            }
        ).appendTo("#container");
    }

    var mid = {
        x: 250,
        y: 250
    };
    var w = 300;

    function circle() {
        for(var n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
            $("#"+n).css("top", (mid.y + (Math.sin(Math.PI/((n+1)/100)) * w/2)));
            $("#"+n).css("left", (mid.x + (Math.cos(Math.PI/((n+1)/100)) * w/2)));
        }
    }

    function square() {
        // top
        var n = 0;
        for(; n < 25; ++n) {
            $("#"+n).css("top", mid.y - 150);
            $("#"+n).css("left", w * (n/25) + mid.x / 2);
        }
        // right
        for(; n < 50; ++n) {
            $("#"+n).css("top", (w * ((n-25)/25)) + mid.y/2);
            $("#"+n).css("left", mid.x + w/2);
        }
        // bottom
        for(; n < 75; ++n) {
            $("#"+n).css("top", mid.y + 300/2);
            $("#"+n).css("left", w * ((n-50)/25) + mid.x / 2);
        }
        // left
        for(; n < 100; ++n) {
            $("#"+n).css("top", (w * ((n-75)/25)) + mid.y/2);
            $("#"+n).css("left", mid.x - w/2);
        }
    }

    var fns = [circle,
               square];

    var idx = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        fns[idx]();
        if(++idx >= fns.length) idx = 0;
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bBEau/1/

Comment: Why bind `this` when you dont use it

Comment: Uh, habit? I didn't even notice that I stuck that in there :P

Comment: Small thing, id cannot start with number.

Comment: @WojciechBednarski: Good catch, but it's valid in HTML5 (not that I'd ever use such an ID in a production environment mind you).